# How to load Facebook buttons faster?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I have a website where I'm using facebook button after each post [my website](http://sentencijos.net/mintys/sentencijos). The problem is that it takes a lot of time to load all buttons. Can I do something to make it load faster?

I'm using Facebook SDK. I'm using this code after body tag.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId='myid'&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And the button code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [30 Facebook Like buttons on a page overburden the web browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632452/30-facebook-like-buttons-on-a-page-overburden-the-web-browser)

Comment: Anyone? I need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
   (function(d, s, id) 
   {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.async=true;    
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId='myid'&version=v2.0";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }
   (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```